# Self-willed behavior in response to return from handling of WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm redrawing the non-client area completely, but willing to keep some default functionality. Windows doesn't allow me to put a close button wherever I want. Though it perfectly works when I say to windows that I want the whole window to be HTCAPTION, but not a close button. I know I can easily go around and make an appropriate direct api call. But there are always some doubts, what if windows do some extra things that I'm not aware of. Why do Windows do this? Maybe there is some solution that you know. Please, share.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK msg_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE); // inform frame change
        break;
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (wParam) return 0; // removing the standard frame
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCLOSE; // HTCAPTION perfectly works 
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = msg_proc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"huge close button";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        L"huge close button", L"huge close button", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 1000, 1000,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0 );
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

This code means that wherever a user presses a mouse button an application should close. But that's not the case.

Comment: case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;

Comment: @HansPassant, I forgot about this for the example, but it does not help. The problem is in windows handling of HTCLOSE. It assumes that the button always must be a rect defined by windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) separately.

> wParam
>
> The hit-test value returned by the DefWindowProc function as a result
> of processing the WM_NCHITTEST message. For a list of hit-test values,
> see WM_NCHITTEST.

Therefore, the value you return from `WM_NCHITTEST` is sent in the `wParam` of other messages, notably `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_NCLBUTTONUP`.

Modify it like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK msg_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE); // inform frame change
        break;
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (wParam) return 0; // removing the standard frame
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCLOSE; // HTCAPTION perfectly works
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
        if (wParam == HTCLOSE)
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed 3 downvotes to get the answer. I don't quite understand why people don't like it. Maybe the title is bad.

Comment: Or maybe they don't like the idea of this beautiful program.

Comment: @olekstolar Don't mind this, all you need to do is to ask questions and give enough details.